# Which way of programmatically referencing a CSS class is most reliable?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2010, createchildcontrols

In my Sharepoint project, I am dynamically creating controls in the overridden CreateChildControls() method. I don't know which of the two ways to reference the .css file is preferred:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    // Way 1
    // from http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/programmatically-add-js-css-to-pages
    this.Controls.Add(new CssRegistration()
    {
        Name = "/_layouts/ucsc_web_forms.css"
    });

    // Way 2
    HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();
    cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    cssLink.Attributes.Add("href", "/_layouts/duckbilled_platypi_rus.css");
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);

    boxPayeeName = new TextBox();
    boxPayeeName.CSSClass = "duck-billed-platypi";
    boxPayeeName.Columns = LONG_TEXT_BOX_COL_WIDTH;
}
```

...but figure one of them, at least, should do the trick. Is one methodology to be preferred over the other?

### UPDATE

Based on empirical observation (the empirical strikes back), the second "way" breaks the WebPart, at least mine. The first:

```
this.Controls.Add(new CssRegistration()
{
    Name = "/_layouts/ucsc_web_forms.css"
});
```

...at least "does no harm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (assuming your project has a CSS file named "ucsc_web_forms.css" which has classes named "finaff-webform-field-label" and "finaff-webform-field-input"):

Add the following to CreateChildControls() after "base.CreateChildControls();":

```
this.Controls.Add(new CssRegistration()
{
    Name = "/_layouts/ucsc_web_forms.css"
});
```

...then, creating the dynamic controls likes so works just dandy:

```
LiteralControl reqDateStr = new LiteralControl("<span class=\"finaff-webform-field-label\">Requester Date:</span>");
. . .
boxPayeeName = new TextBox();
boxPayeeName.CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input";
```